# Not getting grouped results when using GROUP BY on a string column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an inbox table where I want to return messaged grouped by their phone_number (like GMail groups by sender). And the sms_content should be the last message by id. But when I use the GROUP BY keyword it doesn't return grouped results.

Here is my "inbox" table. There are 2 message from number "+123456789" that should be grouped.

```
+----+--------------+------------------------------+
| id | phone_number |         sms_content          |
+----+--------------+------------------------------+
|  1 | +123456789   | Hello, my name is            |
|  2 | +987654321   | What's up, long time no see! |
|  3 | +123456789   | John, I want to meet you!    |
+----+--------------+------------------------------+
```

My first query failed with this error message

```
select * from inbox group by phone_number
```

> Error: Error in query: ERROR: column "inbox.id" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

My second query that I tried did not return results grouped by phone_number

```
select *
from inbox
group by phone_number, id, sms_content
order by id desc
```

Result (not grouped):

```
+----+--------------+------------------------------+
| id | phone_number |         sms_content          |
+----+--------------+------------------------------+
|  3 | +123456789   | John, I want to meet you!    |
|  2 | +987654321   | What's up, long time no see! |
|  1 | +123456789   | Hello, my name is            |
+----+--------------+------------------------------+
```

The desired result that I would like to see is this. Phone number field should be grouped and sms_content should show the latest sms_content from that phone number.

```
+--------------+------------------------------+
| phone_number |         sms_content          |
+--------------+------------------------------+
| +123456789   | John, I want to meet you!    |
| +987654321   | What's up, long time no see! |
+--------------+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the max id for each number and then join to the table:

```
select i.phone_number, i.sms_content
from inbox i inner join (
  select phone_number, max(id) maxid
  from inbox 
  group by phone_number
) g on g.maxid = i.id and g.phone_number = i.phone_number
```

Or with not exists:

```
select i.phone_number, i.sms_content
from inbox i
where not exists (
  select 1 from inbox
  where phone_number = i.phone_number and id > i.id
)
```

Comment: Also, the fastest execution time from all answers.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has a useful standard extension for this case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (phone_number)
       phone_number,
       sms_content
FROM inbox
ORDER BY phone_number, id DESC
```

[Details](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html):

> `SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] )` keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal.

([Sample fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t8bauDSVE98UYnXoqvVFKv/0))

Comment: This seems very elegant, too bad it only for PostgreSQL. But in my case that's what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: You specified PostgreSQL, of course you will get PostgreSQL answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id,phone_number
      ,sms_content

from inbox

where id in(
            Select MAX(id) AS id
            FROM inbox
            group by phone_number
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number like this:

```
select * from (   
     select phone_number, sms_content, 
     row_number() over(partition by phone_number order by id desc) as rn
     from inbox
) t
where 
rn = 1
```

Comment: That seems overly complicated to simply group messages. Is it possible to do it in a more simple query?

Answer (score 0):

select max(id), phone_number, 
sms_content from inbox
group by phone_number

Comment: ERROR: column "inbox.sms_content" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function